# Parsing datetime value using strptime() problem

Tags: python, python-datetime, strptime

I try to convert data like

```
'2021-07-06T07:31:02Z'
```

to a `datetime` using this way

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(created, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

but got the error

```
time data '2021-07-06T07:31:02Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no `.%f` in your time string…

Answer (score 2):

You are using `%f` in your code, but your aren't giving a fraction in your string example.
I tried the following which worked:

```
datetime.strptime('2021-07-06T07:31:02Z','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
Out[14]: datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 6, 7, 31, 2)
```

So either remove the `.%f` or add the fraction value to your string.

For more info:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior